# fpdf - printing PDF gets screwed up depending on computer

Tags: php, pdf, printing, fpdf

So I coded a PDF document using fpdf (PHP)

However when we go to print these documents it seems to print correctly from my computer, but when I print from my bosses laptop it screws things up.

The only difference is he has installed the HP settings and I have not.

here is my code maybe something wrong in there?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","DBUSER","DBPASS");
mysql_select_db("DB");
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('header.png',10,0,200);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

// Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);

    //$this->Image('footer.png',0,200,'210%');
    // Arial italic 8
    //$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    //$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}

$pdf=new FPDF();

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$arr = array($_GET['ids']);
reset($arr);
while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {

$result=mysql_query("SELECT customer.* FROM customer_detail as customer WHERE customer.customer_id IN ({$value})");
$number_of_customers = mysql_numrows($result);



//For each row, add the field to the corresponding column
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage(); 
    $name = "";
    $TradingName = "";
    $Street = "";
    $City = "";
    $state = "";


    $name = ucfirst($row["FirstName"])." ".ucfirst($row["LastName"]);
    $TradingName = $row["TradingName"];
    $Street = $row["Street"];
    $City = $row["City"];
    $state = $row["State"];

    if($state == 1)
    {
    $states = "VIC";
    }
    else if($state == 2)
    {
    $states = "NSW";
    }
    else if($state == 3)
    {
    $states = "QLD";
    }
    else if($state == 4)
    {
    $states = "WA";
    }
    else if($state == 5)
    {
    $states = "TAS";
    }
    else if($state == 6)
    {
    $states = "SA";
    }
    else if($state == 7)
    {
    $states = "ACT";
    }
    else if($state == 8)
    {
    $states = "NT";
    } 

    $PostCode = $row["PostCode"];

    $TradingName_code = $TradingName_code.$TradingName."\n";
    $Name_Code = $Name_code.$name."\n";
    $Address_code = $Address_Code.$Street."\n";
    $StateCityPostcode_code = $City." ".$states." ".$PostCode."\n";





//Create lines (boxes) for each ROW (Product)
//If you don't use the following code, you don't create the lines separating each row





// Instanciation of inherited class
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Ln(60);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,65);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$TradingName,0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,70);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$name,0,1);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,75);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$Street,0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,80);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$StateCityPostcode_code,0,1);
    $pdf->Ln(30);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"Dear ". ucfirst($row['FirstName']),0,1);
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->Write(5,'Thank you and welcome to the Company program.');
    $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->Write(5,'Please find enclosed your preliminary iNcard to access our Company program.');
    $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->Write(5,'An Company representative will contact you by telephone in the next couple of days to assist you in validating your iNcard. To allow us to complete your business listing and start promoting it to over 300,000 of our iNcard holders, the validation process is as follows:');
    $pdf->SetXY(25,170);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"1. Your iNcard is activated over the phone and loaded with $1",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,175);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"2. An SMS confirmation is then sent to your mobile number",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,180);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"3. Once received, please run the $1.00 transaction through your EFTPOS terminal",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,185);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"4. You will then receive a follow up call to nominate a user name unique to your business",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,190);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"and to capture  your business details",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,195);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"5. A password is then supplied to enable you to access your account activities ",0,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(25,200);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"via http://manage.URL.com.au ",0,1);
    $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->Write(5,"Once again, welcome to the program and should you require any assistance or clarification on any of the above points please do not hesitate to contact us.");
    $pdf->Ln(12);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"Kind regards,",0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"Retail Support",0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"Comp Pty Ltd",0,1);



}
mysql_close();
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  Do you know if the file is being sent to the printer or not?   Also is the line $pdf->Output();
 putting out consistent output?

Comment: Not Sure - we still have to manually download the pdf, and hit print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem with your code. It has more to do with different settings on different computers. Your boss might have some settings which controls the page layout and thus the printed page looks different compared to when you print it without those settings.